# Ошибка mysql_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql

В логе сайта появляется ошибка:

> mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **mysql.class.php on line 37**

```
function findpole1($id,$table){

   mysql_connect($GLOBALS["hostname"],$GLOBALS["username"],$GLOBALS["password"]) or die("");
   $result=mysql_db_query($GLOBALS["dbname"],"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$id'");

   //*****************line38********************************

    $find=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo $find[2];

}
```

А сам **mysql_fetch_object** появляется в этом же файле чуть позже

```
static  function query($sql,$default=0){

    if ($default==1) { echo '<div style="border: solid 1px red">'.$sql.'</div>'; }

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $a=array();
    while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                $a[]=$obj;
    }

    return $a;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить на эту строчку:

```
$result = mysql_db_query($GLOBALS["dbname"], "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Comment: Добавил исправление

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Ошибка не выскакивает, но инфа в БД в опредеоенных случаях как не сохранялась, так и не сохраняется. error-log чистый....

Comment: Я извиняюсь,вчера кое-что напутал, ОШИБКА осталась.